# Як правильно робити морфологічний розбір слова?

Tags: морфологія

Підскажіть, будь ласка, як правильно зробити морфологічний розбір слова. Дякую

Comment: Дуже похвально, що ви намагаєтеся відредагувати запитання, але мушу сказати, що зміни, які внесені, є недостатніми. Для того, щоб запитання стало якісним, воно має бути точним і воно повинно демонструвати спробу самостійно відповісти. Загальні правила морфологічного розбору є в підручниках, і робити копію підручника сенсу нема. Але якщо ви зіткнулися з якоюсь конкретною проблемою, то вкажіть, у чому са́ме вона полягає. Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [ask] а також
[«Якими мають бути гарні запитання і відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/).

Comment: Добре, вибачте за незручності. Буду намагатися виправитись. Дякую.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Усе залежить від частини мови.
Наприклад, інформацію брала із [Острів знань](http://shkola.ostriv.in.ua/publication/code-1632B12EFF6C6/list-B407A47B26):

> **Іменник**
>
> 1. Початкова форма.
> 2. На яке питання відповідає в реченні.
> 3. Істота чи неістота.
> 4. Власна чи загальна назва.
> 5. Конкретне чи абстрактне значення, збірне, речовинне.
> 6. Рід, число, відмінок, відміна, група (тверда, м’яка, мішана).
> 7. Спосіб творення (якщо це похідне слово).
> 8. Правопис.
> 9. Синтаксична роль у реченні.
>
> **Прикметник**
>
> 1. Початкова форма.
> 2. На яке питання відповідає в реченні.
> 3. Розряд за значенням: якісний, відносний чи присвійний.
> 4. Форма: повна чи коротка.
> 5. Для якісних – ступінь порівняння.
> 6. Група: тверда або м’яка.
> 7. Рід, число, відмінок.
> 8. Спосіб творення, якщо слово похідне.
> 9. Особливості правопису.
> 10. Синтаксична роль у реченні.
>
> **Числівник**
>
> 1. Початкова форма.
> 2. На яке питання відповідає в реченні.
> 3. Розряд за значенням: кількісний (дробовий, збірний), порядковий.
> 4. Група за будовою: простий, складний чи складений.
> 5. Рід, число (якщо є), відмінок.
> 6. Спосіб творення, якщо слово похідне.
> 7. Правопис.
> 8. Синтаксична роль у реченні.
>
> **Займенник**
>
> 1. Початкова форма.
> 2. На яке питання відповідає
> 3. Розряд за значенням: особовий, зворотний, присвійний, вказівний, означальний, питальний, відносний, неозначений, заперечний.
> 4. Рід, число, відмінок.
> 5. Спосіб творення.
> 6. Синтаксична роль.
>
> **Дієслово**
>
> 1. Початкова форма.
> 2. На яке питання відповідає.
> 3. Дієслівна форма: інфінітив, особова форма, родова, безособові дієслова, дієслова на –но, -то, дієприкметник, дієприслівник.
> 4. Перехідне чи неперехідне.
> 5. Вид.
> 6. Спосіб: дійсний, умовний, наказовий.
> 7. Час, проста чи складена форма.
> 8. Якщо теперішній чи майбутній час, визначити особу та число.
> 9. Якщо минулий час, умовний спосіб, то треба визначити рід в однині.
> 10. Дієвідміна.
>
> !!! Є така схема розбору наступних форм дієслова (однак нижче подаю чіткішу):
>
> Якщо дієприкметник, то назвати такі ознаки: активний чи пасивний, час, вид, рід, число, відмінок.
>
> Якщо дієприслівник, то назвати такі граматичні ознаки: час, вид.
>
> 11. Особливості творення.
> 12. Правопис.
> 13. Синтаксична роль.
>
> **Прислівник**
>
> 1. На яке питання відповідає.
> 2. Розряд за значенням: означальний, обставинний (місця, часу…).
> 3. Для якісно-означальних – ступінь порівняння.
> 4. Спосіб творення, від якої частини мови утворений.
> 5. Правопис.
> 6. Cинтаксична роль.
>
> **Прийменник**
>
> 1. Службова частина мови.
> 2. Група за походженням: первинний, вторинний.
> 3. Група за будовою: простий, складний, складений.
> 4. З якою відмінковою формою вживається.
>
> **Сполучник**
>
> 1. Службова частина мови.
> 2. Розряд: сурядний, підрядний.
> 3. За вживанням: одиничний, парний, повторюваний.
> 4. Група за будовою: простий, складний, складений.
> 5. Правопис.
> 6. Синтаксична роль.
>
> **Частка**
>
> 1. Службова частина мови.
> 2. Група за значенням і вживанням.
>
> **Вигук**
>
> 1. Окрема частина мови, що виражає емоції. Волевиявлення, звукові реакції мовця, етикет.
> 2. Розряд за значенням: емоційний, спонукальний, звуконаслідування, звертання до тварин, мовний етикет.
> 3. Роль у реченні, розділові знаки при вигуку.

Щодо дієприкметника та дієприслівника, раджу сайт http://online-hw.com/content/s_t-pravila/rozbori.html, де подано:

> Морфологічний розбір **дієприкметника**
>
> 1. Особлива форма дієслова.
> 2. Початкова форма (дієприкметник у називному відмінку чоловічого роду однини).
> 3. Активний чи пасивний.
> 4. Вид (доконаний, недоконаний).
> 5. Час (теперішній, минулий).
> 6. Число.
> 7. Рід (в однині).
> 8. Відмінок.
> 9. Синтаксична роль.

**Зразок**

Мамин хліб був обсипаний зернятками тмину.

Обсипаний – дієприкметник, поч. ф. обсипаний, пасивний, доконаний вид, минулий час, однина, чоловічий рід, називний відм., присудок.

> Морфологічний розбір **дієприслівника**
>
> 1. Особлива форма дієслова.
> 2. Вид (доконаний, недоконаний).
> 3. Час (теперішній, минулий).
> 4. Перехідність (перехідний, неперехідний).
> 5. Синтаксична роль.

**Зразок**

Білий димок, хвилюючись, здіймається догори.

Хвилюючись – дієприслівник, недоконаний вид, теперішній час, неперехідний, обставина.

Comment: Не варто вставляти пробіли (проміжки) на початку рядка. Таке форматування призначене для програмного коду (`такий текст` має негарний шрифт, сірий фон і неправильно читається [екранними читачами](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Читач_екрана), що їх люди використовують через вади зору або для зручності). Зате ви можете почати рядок з цифри і крапки (наприклад, `0.  Початкова форма` чи `1. Початкова форма` — це означатиме автоматичнонумерований перелік) або з зірочки чи дефіс-мінуса (`* Початкова форма` чи `- Початкова форма` — це означатиме маркований перелік).

Comment: Тепер уже все гаразд чи ще щось потрібно зробити?

Comment: Якща Вам самій таке оформлення подобається — то все гаразд (ну, наприклад, я не знаю, чому на оригінальному сайті пункти нумерують, а Ви ні — чи це навмисне, чи це випадково).

Comment: Якщо я правильно зрозуміла, то Ви це мали на увазі? Я правильно виправила?

Comment: Коли є володіння анґліьської, то про формати можна почитати [тут](//meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Добре, дякую за покликання!